# PIC16 Timer - BTFSS not working correctly?

Tags: assembly, pic

I'm a total Beginner in PIC/Assembly programming and was trying to code a 1s delay for my University-Class. I'm using mplab with the inbuild simulator and picsimlab.
This is my Code:

```
; PIC16F877A Configuration Bit Settings

; Assembly source line config statements

; CONFIG
  CONFIG  FOSC = HS             ; Oscillator Selection bits (HS oscillator)
  CONFIG  WDTE = OFF            ; Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT disabled)
  CONFIG  PWRTE = OFF           ; Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
  CONFIG  BOREN = ON            ; Brown-out Reset Enable bit (BOR enabled)
  CONFIG  LVP = ON              ; Low-Voltage (Single-Supply) In-Circuit Serial Programming Enable bit (RB3/PGM pin has PGM function; low-voltage programming enabled)
  CONFIG  CPD = OFF             ; Data EEPROM Memory Code Protection bit (Data EEPROM code protection off)
  CONFIG  WRT = OFF             ; Flash Program Memory Write Enable bits (Write protection off; all program memory may be written to by EECON control)
  CONFIG  CP = OFF              ; Flash Program Memory Code Protection bit (Code protection off)

// config statements should precede project file includes.
#include <xc.inc>
  
PSECT resetVec,global,class=CODE,delta=2,abs
ORG 0h
resetVec:
    pagesel main
    goto main
        
    
PSECT code
main:
    BANKSEL INTCON
    movlw 0xA0h
    movwf INTCON
    BANKSEL OPTION_REG
    movlw 0x00h
    movwf OPTION_REG
    BANKSEL TRISD
    movlw 0x00h
    movwf TRISD
    movwf TRISB
    BANKSEL TMR0
    movlw 0x01h
    movwf PORTD
    movlw 0xFEh
    movwf TMR0
 
loop:
    call delay  
    RLF PORTD
    goto loop
    
delay:
    movlw 0x4Ch     ;76 timer cycles
    movwf PORTB     ;using PORTB to count down to zero
delay_loop:
    BTFSS INTCON, 2 ;when timer flows over, INTCON,2 will be set
    goto $-1        ;return until timer flows over
    BCF INTCON, 2   ;reset overflow bit
    decfsz PORTB,1  ;decrement PORTB until 0
    goto delay_loop 
    return      ;return to loop
```

The Idea is to set the prescaler to 256, which (with a 20Mhz clock) should lead to a 13,1 ms Timer-Cycle, then loop through this 76 times getting roughly a 1s delay.
Everything is set up fine (TMR0 is set to 254 and prescaler to 1 for debugging purposes), but after the OF-bit of TMR0 is set, the program jumps back to main and I just don't understand why...
I already tried using a different register than PORTB, result is the same.
It calls "BTFSS INTCON, 2" one last time, does not call "goto $-1" nor "BCF INTCON, 2" or anything after, just jumps straight to main again.
Help will be much appreciated :D
best Regards

Comment: You are actually enabling interrupts - but don't have an interrupt handler.  And your `main` happens to be at the address where the interrupt handler would be located...  On PICs at least, you do not need to enable interrupts if you're just going to poll the flag bit for some specific interrupt.

Comment: YOO thank you!!! 
At first I wanted to use an interrupt but we didn't have this yet in class so I went back to polling and forgot to disable the interrupts (also didn't know I need to^^)